# Penalty for accidentally overstaying in Sweden by 1 day? (US citizen)

Tags: schengen, overstaying, visa-free-entry, sweden

I stay 90 days in/90 days out of Sweden on a consistent basis to be with my fiance as much as possible while he finishes his studies (only 1 1/2 years left now, thank god!) We have been doing this dance for the last 2 1/2 years.

We booked this trip about 6 months ago, right before my last visit, as we always do. We do this because we like to stay one trip ahead to save money and decrease anxiety about booking tickets in time.

We must have miscalculated because upon checking with the Schengen calculator, it is saying that I am entering 1 day early. Basically, I stayed 89 days last time (June 18,2018-September 14,2018) and the day I return (December 13th, 2018) will be day 90 of staying in Sweden since my last date of entry (June 18, 2018). My timer resets on December 15th, so December 14th will be day 91.

I have been trying my very best to stay within the rules and regulations with absolutely no intention of breaking or disrespecting any of Sweden's immigration laws, and that would be obvious to anyone who looked at my passport history for the last 2+ years. I have not overstayed a single time, or if I have it was not intentional or to my knowledge, nor was it ever brought to my attention upon entering/exiting Sweden.

However, now that I have come across my first mistake, I am absolutely petrified of what the consequences might be when I arrive at passport control. I am hoping that nothing happens, but I would be totally understanding even if I had to pay a fine. Anything but a travel ban or deportation. Do you think I would be deported or banned for a miscalculation error (my first one in 2+ years at that)? I also have a return ticket already for March 13, 2019 (90 days after my date of entry) which I can easily present to the passport control officer if requested.

I really hope that someone here can ease my mind regarding this situation. I understand that laws are laws and I am in no way immune from following these laws. But do the immigration officers tend to allow a little wiggle room for human error in obvious cases of genuine mistakes like these?

Please, if anyone has any experience with a similar situation, let me know.

Comment: alright guys i rebooked my ticket to arrive on the 15th just to be safe, thanks for all the answers :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86836/discussion-on-question-by-bailey-kahn-penalty-for-accidentally-overstaying-in-sw).